# How do you rotate the standard basis to line up with a given vector?

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a vector $\mathbf{a}$ I want to transform the standard basis $\{\mathbf{e}_1, \dots, \mathbf{e}_n\}$ so that
$$
\mathbf{e}_1 \mapsto \mathbf{a}
$$
while the remaining vectors are rotated so that they again form an orthogonal basis. Another way to state this is that I want to rotate the hyperplane orthogonal to $\mathbf{e}_1$ so that it is now orthogonal to $\mathbf{a}$. Now there are many linear transformations that accomplish this. But intuition suggests that there ought to be a *simplest* such transformation which doesn't also mirror the plane or any other funky business. Does somebody have a suggestion?

Comment: I guess it's somewhat arbitrary to set an orthonormal basis on $a^\perp$. Think about $n=3$, then there's a whole plane (circle), $a^\perp$ for $e_2$ to go to, and I can't see any preference..

Comment: The preference would be to minimize the distance $\mathbf{e}_2$ has to move (presumably in the Euclidean norm). Though, any concrete transformation with a simple description would be a start.